# How to register content changes to a controlled input field?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to register a change to the contents of an input field and trigger a follow-up action based on the change. That means, for example, if an input field has the initial value " Initial value" and the last character "e" is removed and then added again, this should not be registered as a change. However, if the last character "e" is replaced with, say, a "z", the change must be registered.

My approach is to store the initial value in a separate variable and then compare this value with the value of the onchange handler. However, I am stuck with storing the "initial value" in a separate variable, how can I capture the initial value of the input field so that I can later compare it to the actual input?

[Please see here my problem in sandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-brattain-3mk4b?file=/src/App.js)

```
export default function App(initialValue) {

  const [textFieldInput, setTextFieldInput] = useState(initialValue="Starting Value");
  const [inputChanged, setinputChanged] = useState(false);

  function onChangeTextFieldInput(e) {
    const input = e.target.value;
    setTextFieldInput(input);
 
  }

  function onClickButton (e){
    console.log("Value Saved")
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={onChangeTextFieldInput}
        value={textFieldInput}
        placeholder="Enter Here Text"
      />
      <button
                disabled={inputChanged?false:true}
                onClick={onClickButton}
            >
                Save
            </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
export default function App({ initialTextFieldInput = "initial value" }) {
  const [textFieldInput, setTextFieldInput] = useState(initialTextFieldInput);

  function onChangeTextFieldInput(e) {
    const input = e.target.value;

    if (initialTextFieldInput === input) {
      console.log("inital value and current value are same");
      console.log(
        `current value: ${input} initial value: ${initialTextFieldInput}`
      );
      setTextFieldInput(input);
      return;
    }

    console.log(
      `current value: ${input} initial value: ${initialTextFieldInput}`
    );
    setTextFieldInput(input);
    console.log(input);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={onChangeTextFieldInput}
        value={textFieldInput}
        placeholder="Enter Here Text"
      />
      {initialTextFieldInput === textFieldInput && (
        <div>inital value and current value are same</div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```